# Random disconnections using Google Game Services Realtime Multiplayer

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

we're developing an android game using Google Game ServicesRealtime Multiplayer that needs 4 players in order to start a match successfully. It seems the game mechanics are working fine, but we have constant random disconnections from one of the four devices playing, getting onP2PDisconnected over and over, making the game to cancel. We could say that if we try it ten times, we can play a successful match once or twice.

We're really getting desperate with that issue, as we don't know if we did something wrong, or Google Game Services is this unstable. Has anyone experienced this kind of behaviour using it?

I attach log portions that may hint a clue.

Thanks for taking the time to read :)

```
05-26 14:07:31.741: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): adding the realtime message listener: RealTimeMessageReceivedListener class instance from Unity
05-26 14:07:31.788: W/GLSUser(728): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-26 14:07:31.878: D/dalvikvm(746): GC_EXPLICIT freed 237K, 35% free 6869K/10439K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 54ms
05-26 14:07:31.936: D/dalvikvm(728): GC_EXPLICIT freed 851K, 46% free 4590K/8387K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 55ms
05-26 14:07:31.987: W/GLSUser(728): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-26 14:07:32.503: W/GLSUser(728): [asb][asb] Permission for com.BitologyStudios.Buticat to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appstate https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login will be managed remotely.
05-26 14:07:32.557: I/libjingle(6011): Token type:OAuth2
05-26 14:07:32.557: I/libjingle(6011): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
05-26 14:07:32.694: I/libjingle(6011): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
05-26 14:07:32.866: I/libjingle(6011): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): Starting Jingle info task.
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): ProcessStart()::Sending Jingle info stanza.
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): BuzzSubscriptionsTask::SubscribeTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): void games_rtmp::BuzzSubscription::CheckOverride(): Channel GAMES_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL default: games.google.com
05-26 14:07:33.499: I/libjingle(6011): void games_rtmp::BuzzSubscription::CheckOverride(): Notifier GAMES_NOTIFICATION_JID default: games@google.com
05-26 14:07:33.503: I/libjingle(6011): void games_rtmp::BuzzSubscription::CheckOverride(): Channel GAMES_BUZZBOT_CHANNEL default: games.google.com/buzzbot
05-26 14:07:33.503: I/libjingle(6011): void games_rtmp::BuzzSubscription::CheckOverride(): Notifier GAMES_BUZZBOT_JID default: play-presence@games.bot.talk.google.com
05-26 14:07:33.503: I/libjingle(6011): SUBSCRIBE STANZA: <cli:iq type="set" to="games@ob.talk.google.com" id="9" xmlns:cli="jabber:client"><subscribe xmlns="google:push"><item channel="games.google.com" from="games@google.com"/><item channel="games.google.com/buzzbot" from="play-presence@games.bot.talk.google.com"/></subscribe></cli:iq>
05-26 14:07:33.503: I/libjingle(6011): Send Stanza return ok:
05-26 14:07:33.585: I/libjingle(6011): OnJingleInfo called. Setting relay/stun hosts.
05-26 14:07:33.671: I/libjingle(6011): SubscribeTask HandleStanza : <cli:iq to="games@ob.talk.google.com/games_andr7FAD538A" from="games@ob.talk.google.com" id="9" type="result" xmlns:cli="jabber:client"/>
05-26 14:07:33.671: I/libjingle(6011): void games_rtmp::BuzzSubscriptionsTask::SubscriptionSuccess(): Subscription Successful.
05-26 14:07:33.710: W/GLSUser(728): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-26 14:07:34.315: I/qtaguid(746): Failed write_ctrl(u 46) res=-1 errno=22
05-26 14:07:34.315: I/qtaguid(746): Untagging socket 46 failed errno=-22
05-26 14:07:34.315: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(746): untagSocket(46) failed with errno -22
05-26 14:07:34.346: I/libjingle(6011): virtual int games_rtmp::BuzzSubscriptionsTask::SetOnDisconnectTask::ProcessStart(): Send-on-disconnect: <cli:message to="games@ob.talk.google.com" type="headline" xmlns:cli="jabber:client"><push xmlns="google:push" channel="games.google.com/buzzbot" sendOnDisconnect="true"><recipient to="play-presence@games.bot.talk.google.com">Q2hvS0NRaTJ1SWZReEJrUUFoQUJHQUFnX19fX19fX19fX19fQVJEVGdzenEzNjNid0VnOmdhbWVzQG9iLnRhbGsuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9nYW1lc19hbmRyN0ZBRDUzOEE=</recipient></push></cli:message>
05-26 14:07:34.350: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onRoomCreated RoomEntity{RoomId=ChoKCQi2uIfQxBkQAhABGAAg____________ARDTgszq363bwEg, CreatorId=p_CNOCzOrfrdvASBAB, CreationTimestamp=1401106053994, RoomStatus=1, Description=null, Variant=0, AutoMatchCriteria=Bundle[{max_automatch_players=3, min_automatch_players=3, exclusive_bit_mask=0}], Participants=[ParticipantEntity{Player=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=105628884802350980413, DisplayName=Taty Tetatova, IconImageUri=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null, HiResImageUrl=null, RetrievedTimestamp=1401106054336}, Status=2, ClientAddress=null, ConnectedToRoom=false, DisplayName=Taty Tetatova, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=null, Capabilities=0, Result=null}], AutoMatchWaitEstimateSeconds=-1}
05-26 14:07:34.350: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): room update statusCode: 0
05-26 14:07:34.350: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): STATUS_OK
05-26 14:07:34.526: I/ActivityManager(490): START {act=com.google.android.gms.games.SHOW_REAL_TIME_WAITING_ROOM dat=version:4323000 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.client.matches.RealTimeWaitingRoomActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 6734
05-26 14:07:34.635: W/PopupManager(2476): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
05-26 14:07:34.768: D/dalvikvm(490): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2747K, 34% free 14085K/21319K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 105ms
05-26 14:07:34.835: D/AudioSpeexSRC(93): AudioResamplerSpeex::~AudioResamplerSpeex()
05-26 14:07:34.885: I/ActivityManager(490): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.client.matches.RealTimeWaitingRoomActivity: +266ms
05-26 14:07:34.932: I/WaitingRoom(2476): Room status after registering listener: 1
05-26 14:07:41.213: I/libjingle(6011): Attempting to create a session, with data only.
05-26 14:07:41.213: I/libjingle(6011): CompleteInitiateCall_w:remoteJid=1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780
05-26 14:07:41.213: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnCallCreate(cricket::Call*): Connecting to OnAddSession
05-26 14:07:41.213: E/libjingle(6011): Error(mediasession.cc:529): cricket::SessionDescription* cricket::MediaSessionDescriptionFactory::CreateOffer(const cricket::MediaSessionOptions&, const cricket::SessionDescription*): Creating Data offer.
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): AddSession() called. has_data = 1
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): Creating data channel.
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): Is worker current:0
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): Current thread:0x400415f0
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): worker_thread:0x5c909c78 initialized=1
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): Created channel for data
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): DataChannel::Init() called
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): result = 1
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnAddSession(cricket::Call*, cricket::Session*): OnAddSession called.
05-26 14:07:41.217: I/libjingle(6011): Setting local data description
05-26 14:07:41.221: I/libjingle(6011): Added data send stream '' with ssrc=3162199197
05-26 14:07:41.221: I/libjingle(6011): Add send ssrc: 3162199197
05-26 14:07:41.221: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.225: I/libjingle(6011): Channel enabled
05-26 14:07:41.225: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.229: I/libjingle(6011): bool talk_base::BasicNetworkManager::CreateNetworks(bool, talk_base::NetworkManager::NetworkList*) const: Added network:192.168.1.132
05-26 14:07:41.229: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest start: relay.google.com/create_session?username=Bh6YrC6zwcQVzp9V&password=qUCrZPThCgooX5z%2fiTiyJf7F&sn=3
05-26 14:07:41.229: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:41.260: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onPeerJoined
05-26 14:07:41.268: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onRoomConnecting
05-26 14:07:41.338: I/libjingle(6011): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
05-26 14:07:41.338: I/libjingle(6011): BeginSSL: relay.google.com
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): Parsing Jingle data content
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnCallCreate(cricket::Call*): Connecting to OnAddSession
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): Calling Call::IncomingSession()
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): AddSession() called. has_data = 1
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): Creating data channel.
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): Is worker current:0
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): Current thread:0x400415f0
05-26 14:07:41.436: I/libjingle(6011): worker_thread:0x5c909c78 initialized=1
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): Created channel for data
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): DataChannel::Init() called
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): Setting remote data description
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): Added data recv stream '' with ssrc=4000049525
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): Add remote ssrc: 4000049525
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): DataMediaChannel::SetSendBandwidth to 10485000bps.
05-26 14:07:41.440: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.444: I/libjingle(6011): result = 1
05-26 14:07:41.444: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnAddSession(cricket::Call*, cricket::Session*): OnAddSession called.
05-26 14:07:41.444: I/libjingle(6011): Setting local data description
05-26 14:07:41.444: I/libjingle(6011): Added data send stream '' with ssrc=450563253
05-26 14:07:41.444: I/libjingle(6011): Add send ssrc: 450563253
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): SRTP reset to init state
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): Channel enabled
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest start: relay.google.com/create_session?username=ZJsAzPVE3kOvJkbT&password=MGWJ2gOJVdMwCWKt2jhZR70w&sn=3
05-26 14:07:41.448: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:41.487: I/libjingle(6011): Parsing Jingle data content
05-26 14:07:41.487: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnCallCreate(cricket::Call*): Connecting to OnAddSession
05-26 14:07:41.487: I/libjingle(6011): Calling Call::IncomingSession()
05-26 14:07:41.487: I/libjingle(6011): AddSession() called. has_data = 1
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Creating data channel.
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Is worker current:0
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Current thread:0x400415f0
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): worker_thread:0x5c909c78 initialized=1
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Created channel for data
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): DataChannel::Init() called
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Setting remote data description
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Added data recv stream '' with ssrc=514262018
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Add remote ssrc: 514262018
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): DataMediaChannel::SetSendBandwidth to 10485000bps.
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): result = 1
05-26 14:07:41.491: I/libjingle(6011): void gtalk::LibjingleClient::OnAddSession(cricket::Call*, cricket::Session*): OnAddSession called.
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Setting local data description
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Added data send stream '' with ssrc=1308220470
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Add send ssrc: 1308220470
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): SRTP reset to init state
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=0 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Channel enabled
05-26 14:07:41.495: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.499: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest start: relay.google.com/create_session?username=AIMDlmDJTunhH0AS&password=li%2bSYsj9e6VEmG8gUoo6LhdN&sn=3
05-26 14:07:41.503: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:41.565: I/libjingle(6011): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
05-26 14:07:41.565: I/libjingle(6011): BeginSSL: relay.google.com
05-26 14:07:41.573: I/libjingle(6011): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
05-26 14:07:41.573: I/libjingle(6011): BeginSSL: relay.google.com
05-26 14:07:41.659: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest completed successfully
05-26 14:07:41.694: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): Parsing Jingle data content
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest completed successfully
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): Setting remote data description
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): Added data recv stream '' with ssrc=441227590
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): Add remote ssrc: 441227590
05-26 14:07:41.823: I/libjingle(6011): SRTP reset to init state
05-26 14:07:41.827: I/libjingle(6011): DataMediaChannel::SetSendBandwidth to 10485000bps.
05-26 14:07:41.827: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=0
05-26 14:07:41.827: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:41.874: I/libjingle(6011): HttpRequest completed successfully
05-26 14:07:41.874: I/libjingle(6011): SSL Cleanup
05-26 14:07:42.139: I/libjingle(6011): Channel socket writable (data_rtp) for the first time
05-26 14:07:42.139: W/libjingle(6011): Warning(capabilitiestable.cpp:67): Could not fetch capabilities for peer: 3pkw7iufwb1vm2gmosvgphsm7j@public.talk.google.com/games_andr2E6F8F07
05-26 14:07:42.139: I/libjingle(6011): Unreliable latency protocol not supported by peer: 3pkw7iufwb1vm2gmosvgphsm7j@public.talk.google.com/games_andr2E6F8F07. Latency prober not started.
05-26 14:07:42.143: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=1
05-26 14:07:42.143: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onP2PConnected
05-26 14:07:42.190: W/GLSUser(728): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-26 14:07:42.217: I/libjingle(6011): Channel socket writable (data_rtp) for the first time
05-26 14:07:42.217: W/libjingle(6011): Warning(capabilitiestable.cpp:67): Could not fetch capabilities for peer: 08qxv8ky5i27m02nqevbmxc4q1@public.talk.google.com/games_andr35F372CD
05-26 14:07:42.217: I/libjingle(6011): Unreliable latency protocol not supported by peer: 08qxv8ky5i27m02nqevbmxc4q1@public.talk.google.com/games_andr35F372CD. Latency prober not started.
05-26 14:07:42.217: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=1
05-26 14:07:42.221: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onP2PConnected
05-26 14:07:42.374: I/libjingle(6011): Channel socket writable (data_rtp) for the first time
05-26 14:07:42.374: W/libjingle(6011): Warning(capabilitiestable.cpp:67): Could not fetch capabilities for peer: 1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780
05-26 14:07:42.374: I/libjingle(6011): Unreliable latency protocol not supported by peer: 1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780. Latency prober not started.
05-26 14:07:42.374: I/libjingle(6011): Changing data state, recv=1 send=1
05-26 14:07:42.378: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onP2PConnected
05-26 14:07:42.542: I/qtaguid(746): Failed write_ctrl(u 46) res=-1 errno=22
05-26 14:07:42.542: I/qtaguid(746): Untagging socket 46 failed errno=-22
05-26 14:07:42.542: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(746): untagSocket(46) failed with errno -22
05-26 14:07:42.616: W/GLSUser(728): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-26 14:07:43.163: I/qtaguid(746): Failed write_ctrl(u 46) res=-1 errno=22
05-26 14:07:43.163: I/qtaguid(746): Untagging socket 46 failed errno=-22
05-26 14:07:43.163: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(746): untagSocket(46) failed with errno -22
05-26 14:07:43.225: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onConnectedToRoom
05-26 14:07:43.229: I/libjingle(6011): bool talk_base::BasicNetworkManager::CreateNetworks(bool, talk_base::NetworkManager::NetworkList*) const: Added network:192.168.1.132
05-26 14:07:43.241: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onPeersConnected
05-26 14:07:43.299: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onPeersConnected
05-26 14:07:44.538: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onPeersConnected
05-26 14:07:44.561: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): onRoomConnected RoomEntity{RoomId=ChoKCQi2uIfQxBkQAhABGAAg____________ARDTgszq363bwEg, CreatorId=p_CNOCzOrfrdvASBAB, CreationTimestamp=1401106053994, RoomStatus=3, Description=null, Variant=0, AutoMatchCriteria=Bundle[{max_automatch_players=3, min_automatch_players=3, exclusive_bit_mask=0}], Participants=[ParticipantEntity{Player=null, Status=2, ClientAddress=1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780, ConnectedToRoom=true, DisplayName=Jugador 595, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-9TJK5HKJfSA/UlWL2idXkTI/AAAAAAAAAsk/ZLt-k-oL6oE/s96-ns-s96-ns/, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-9TJK5HKJfSA/UlWL2idXkTI/AAAAAAAAAsk/ZLt-k-oL6oE/s96-ns-s96-ns-s200-ns/, Capabilities=7, Result=null}, ParticipantEntity{Player=null, Status=2, ClientAddress=08qxv8ky5i27m02nqevbmxc4q1@public.talk.google.com/games_andr35F372CD, ConnectedToRoom=true, DisplayName=Jugador 470, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Tj1w4mTrHBQ/UlWL3dD1JJI/AAAAAAAAAsk/yhCkLA4AEDY/s96-ns-s96-ns/, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Tj1w4mTrHBQ/UlWL3dD1JJI/AAAAAAAAAsk/yhCkLA4AEDY/s96-ns-s96-ns-s200-ns/, Capabilities=7, Result=null}, ParticipantEntity{Player=null, Status=2, ClientAddress=3pkw7iufwb1vm2gmosvgphsm7j@public.talk.google.com/games_andr2E6F8F07, ConnectedToRoom=true, DisplayName=Jugador 6745, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uRtLdX69_uE/UlWLz5TGiCI/AAAAAAAAAsk/wIuE4xZ7zC8/s96-ns-s96-ns/, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uRtLdX69_uE/UlWLz5TGiCI/AAAAAAAAAsk/wIuE4xZ7zC8/s96-ns-s96-ns-s200-ns/, Capabilities=7, Result=null}, ParticipantEntity{Player=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=105628884802350980413, DisplayName=Taty Tetatova, IconImageUri=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null, HiResImageUrl=null, RetrievedTimestamp=1401106054336}, Status=2, ClientAddress=null, ConnectedToRoom=true, DisplayName=Taty Tetatova, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=null, Capabilities=0, Result=null}], AutoMatchWaitEstimateSeconds=-1}
05-26 14:07:44.561: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): room update statusCode: 0
05-26 14:07:44.561: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): STATUS_OK
05-26 14:07:44.569: I/WaitingRoom(2476): CALLBACK: onRoomConnected()...
05-26 14:07:44.569: I/WaitingRoom(2476): onRoomConnected: statusCode = 0 for room ID: ChoKCQi2uIfQxBkQAhABGAAg____________ARDTgszq363bwEg
05-26 14:07:45.233: I/libjingle(6011): bool talk_base::BasicNetworkManager::CreateNetworks(bool, talk_base::NetworkManager::NetworkList*) const: Added network:192.168.1.132
05-26 14:07:45.612: D/Prime31-GH(6734): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=35980, resp=RESULT_OK
05-26 14:07:45.612: D/Prime31-GH(6734): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
05-26 14:07:45.612: I/Prime31-RTMP(6734): waiting room result OK. Clear to start the multiplayer game.
05-26 14:07:46.229: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:46.229: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="1" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">RwBpAG0AbQBlAFkAbwB1AHIAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBEAGEAdABhAHwA</ibb:data>
05-26 14:07:46.229: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:46.600: D/AudioSpeexSRC(93): AudioResamplerSpeex::init() mChannelCount=2, mInSampleRate=44100, mSampleRate=44100, mQuality=2
05-26 14:07:46.600: D/AudioSpeexSRC(93): AudioResamplerSpeex::setSampleRate() mChannelCount=2, mInSampleRate=44100->24000, mSampleRate=44100, mQuality=2
05-26 14:07:46.624: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 3pkw7iufwb1vm2gmosvgphsm7j@public.talk.google.com/games_andr2E6F8F07 with data: 0x5bd343d8
05-26 14:07:46.628: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 08qxv8ky5i27m02nqevbmxc4q1@public.talk.google.com/games_andr35F372CD with data: 0x5bd34458
05-26 14:07:46.635: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780 with data: 0x5bd345e8
05-26 14:07:46.858: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:46.858: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="1" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">RwBpAG0AbQBlAFkAbwB1AHIAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBEAGEAdABhAHwA</ibb:data>
05-26 14:07:46.858: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:46.948: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:46.948: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="1" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">RwBpAG0AbQBlAFkAbwB1AHIAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBEAGEAdABhAHwA</ibb:data>
05-26 14:07:46.948: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.077: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.077: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp data back: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="1" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/>
05-26 14:07:47.077: I/libjingle(6011): static void gtalk::LibjingleJniHelper::DispatchIbbSendResult(jobject, const string&, const string&, bool): Dispatch ID:1
05-26 14:07:47.077: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.108: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.108: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp data back: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="2" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/>
05-26 14:07:47.108: I/libjingle(6011): static void gtalk::LibjingleJniHelper::DispatchIbbSendResult(jobject, const string&, const string&, bool): Dispatch ID:2
05-26 14:07:47.108: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.178: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.178: I/libjingle(6011): [1/2] Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="5" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">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
05-26 14:07:47.178: I/libjingle(6011): [2/2] cgBlAGYAZQByAHIAZQBkAFMAYwBvAHIAZQA+AE8AbgBlAEgAdQBuAGQAcgBlAGQATwBuAGUAPAAvAHAAcgBlAGYAZQByAHIAZQBkAFMAYwBvAHIAZQA+AAoAIAAgADwAaQBzAEMAcgBlAGEAdABvAHIAPgB0AHIAdQBlADwALwBpAHMAQwByAGUAYQB0AG8AcgA+AAoAIAAgADwAaQBzAEgAbwBzAHQAPgBmAGEAbABzAGUAPAAvAGkAcwBIAG8AcwB0AD4ACgAgACAAPABpAHMASQBuAEcAYQBtAGUAPgBmAGEAbABzAGUAPAAvAGkAcwBJAG4ARwBhAG0AZQA+AAoAPAAvAFAAYQByAHQAaQBjAGkAcABhAG4AdAA+AA==</ibb:data>
05-26 14:07:47.182: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.194: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.194: I/libjingle(6011): Got Xmpp data back: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="3" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/>
05-26 14:07:47.194: I/libjingle(6011): static void gtalk::LibjingleJniHelper::DispatchIbbSendResult(jobject, const string&, const string&, bool): Dispatch ID:3
05-26 14:07:47.194: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.233: I/libjingle(6011): bool talk_base::BasicNetworkManager::CreateNetworks(bool, talk_base::NetworkManager::NetworkList*) const: Added network:192.168.1.132
05-26 14:07:47.342: I/Choreographer(6734): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-26 14:07:47.342: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 3pkw7iufwb1vm2gmosvgphsm7j@public.talk.google.com/games_andr2E6F8F07 with data: 0x5bd54960
05-26 14:07:47.374: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 08qxv8ky5i27m02nqevbmxc4q1@public.talk.google.com/games_andr35F372CD with data: 0x5bd50bc8
05-26 14:07:47.393: I/libjingle(6011): Sending IBB data message to: 1xa675i84h5j837dnhikjdcka4@public.talk.google.com/games_andrD6E33780 with data: 0x5bd54960
05-26 14:07:47.467: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.467: I/libjingle(6011): [1/2] Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="4" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">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
05-26 14:07:47.471: I/libjingle(6011): [2/2] ZgBlAHIAcgBlAGQAUwBjAG8AcgBlAD4ATwBuAGUASAB1AG4AZAByAGUAZABPAG4AZQA8AC8AcAByAGUAZgBlAHIAcgBlAGQAUwBjAG8AcgBlAD4ACgAgACAAPABpAHMAQwByAGUAYQB0AG8AcgA+AGYAYQBsAHMAZQA8AC8AaQBzAEMAcgBlAGEAdABvAHIAPgAKACAAIAA8AGkAcwBIAG8AcwB0AD4AZgBhAGwAcwBlADwALwBpAHMASABvAHMAdAA+AAoAIAAgADwAaQBzAEkAbgBHAGEAbQBlAD4AZgBhAGwAcwBlADwALwBpAHMASQBuAEcAYQBtAGUAPgAKADwALwBQAGEAcgB0AGkAYwBpAHAAYQBuAHQAPgA=</ibb:data>
05-26 14:07:47.475: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.581: I/libjingle(6011): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
05-26 14:07:47.581: I/libjingle(6011): [1/2] Got Xmpp DATA: <ibb:data ibb:seq="0" ibb:sid="6" xmlns:ibb="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb">VABhAGsAZQBNAHkAUAByAG8AZgBpAGwAZQBEAGEAdABhAHwAPAA/AHgAbQBsACAAdgBlAHIAcwBpAG8AbgA9ACIAMQAuADAAIgAgAGUAbgBjAG8AZABpAG4AZwA9ACIAdQB0AGYALQAxADYAIgA/AD4ACgA8AFAAYQByAHQAaQBjAGkAcABhAG4AdAAgAHgAbQBsAG4AcwA6AHgAcwBpAD0AIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAHcAdwB3AC4AdwAzAC4AbwByAGcALwAyADAAMAAxAC8AWABNAEwAUwBjAGgAZQBtAGEALQBpAG4AcwB0AGEAbgBjAGUAIgAgAHgAbQBsAG4AcwA6AHgAcwBkAD0AIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAHcAdwB3AC4AdwAzAC4AbwByAGcALwAyADAAMAAxAC8AWABNAEwAUwBjAGgAZQBtAGEAIgA+AAoAIAAgADwAcABhAHIAdABpAGMAaQBwAGEAbgB0AEkAZAA+AHAAXwBDAFAAbgB6ADMAdAAyAEEANQBLAG4AeQBiAHgAQQBCADwALwBwAGEAcgB0AGkAYwBpAHAAYQBuAHQASQBkAD4ACgAgACAAPABuAGEAbQBlAD4AUwBhAG4AdABpAGEAZwBvACAAUwBlAGcAdQDtADwALwBuAGEAbQBlAD4ACgAgACAAPAB0AGUAYQBtAD4ATgBvAG4AZQA8AC8AdABlAGEAbQA+AAoAIAAgADwAcAByAGUAZgBlAHIAcgBlAGQAVgBhAHIAaQBhAG4AdAA+AE8AYwBjAGkAZABlAG4AdABhAGwAPAAvAHAAcgBlAGYAZQByAHIAZQBkAFYAYQByAGkAYQBuAHQAPgAKACAAIAA8AHAA
05-26 14:07:47.581: I/libjingle(6011): [2/2] cgBlAGYAZQByAHIAZQBkAFMAYwBvAHIAZQA+AE8AbgBlAEgAdQBuAGQAcgBlAGQATwBuAGUAPAAvAHAAcgBlAGYAZQByAHIAZQBkAFMAYwBvAHIAZQA+AAoAIAAgADwAaQBzAEMAcgBlAGEAdABvAHIAPgBmAGEAbABzAGUAPAAvAGkAcwBDAHIAZQBhAHQAbwByAD4ACgAgACAAPABpAHMASABvAHMAdAA+AGYAYQBsAHMAZQA8AC8AaQBzAEgAbwBzAHQAPgAKACAAIAA8AGkAcwBJAG4ARwBhAG0AZQA+AGYAYQBsAHMAZQA8AC8AaQBzAEkAbgBHAGEAbQBlAD4ACgA8AC8AUABhAHIAdABpAGMAaQBwAGEAbgB0AD4A</ibb:data>
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the cause? I have a similar issue with 2-player real time games.